# Orchard and Facebook

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

For some module, i need to use Facebook XDReceiver.htm, and to use it in module.

What is the best place for this file?

Can i just put it in some folder in my module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to create your own, [simple module](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Creating-a-module-with-a-simple-text-editor.ashx) and place that file inside (for the sake of simplicity and clarity). You could then access it with URL like *http://www.mysite.com/MyModuleProjectName/XDReceiver.htm* (assuming the file would be placed at the module root)

I guess you have some exisiting Facebook-related code, because the XDReceiver.htm file is [no longer needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493271/facebook-new-api-still-require-xdreceiver) for Facebook API to work, as it's using OAuth 2.0 now.

If you are creating a new application and want to wire it with Facebook Connect - there are existing Orchard modules for doing that: [Facebook Connect](http://www.orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.FacebookConnect) and [Open Authentication](http://www.orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.NGM.OpenAuthentication) (which allows user to log into Orchard using Facebook and many other OAuth providers - Twitter, Google etc).

HTH

Comment: Is the Open Authentication module still being worked on? Or are there any better modules available?